# Add namespace to XML node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a piece of XML with the following node

```
<C1478N> xml here </C1478N>
```

How can I add a namespace prefix and url so the XML becomes

```
<en:C1478N xmlns:en="http://test.host.com/C1478N"></en:C1478N>
```

I tried the following XSLT but it's not working

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
                              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                              xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
                              xmlns:ie="http://test.host.com/C1478N" 
                              exclude-result-prefixes="fn xs xsi xsl">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="move-to-namespace">
            <xsl:with-param name="namespace" select="'http://test.host.com/C1478N'"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="move-to-namespace">
        <xsl:param name="namespace"/>
        <xsl:element name="en:{local-name()}" namespace="{$namespace}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any one know what the issue is?

Thanks

Comment: But it **is** working: http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEuV. At least with proper input it is. Your input has an extra `<`, in the closing tag.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake in the question

Comment: Is your processor capable of running xslt 2.0? Because as michael said, the code is working

Comment: @user3520080 Instead of saying "*it's not working*", describe **exactly** what happens - including any error messages.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit vague i'm actually using this transformation within a mule application. The XML passed to the XSL file to be transformed and passed to a JMS outbound queue but the transformation simply does not work. It stays as the original node. I guess I must look elsewhere if the XSL transformation itself is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your transformation will not work with an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Why don't you do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="en:{local-name()}" namespace="http://test.host.com/C1478N">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This ended up being an issue with a transformation I was doing before the XSLT transformation. Both my original and your solution work. The issue wasn't the XSLT after all but thank you for your contribution.